# Make current post the homepage

Tags: posts, homepage

Is there a plugin or code that I can use to make the most current post the homepage of my site. I want to display the actual blog post not a listing as you find in a blog roll.

I have searched for plugins but can't seem to find one that would allow this. I am sure I am not the only person to need this functionality and I am probably not finding the solution out there already.

Frustrated, appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried using a listing of 1? Note that plugin recommendations are off topic here. I'd also suggest redirecting to the latest post instead, as it's better for SEO and caching purposes

Comment: Thank you for the reply Tom.

I am not worried about SEO for my site. I want to stay away from the blog roll look and have it just display the most recent post as the home page.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you post a new article, browsers may serve the older article from cache, as will any social media such as twitter/facebook/etc, redirecting is a much superior solution, and easier to implement. It also avoids the problem of people sharing the content on your homepage via the URL, then having it change without them knowing

Comment: Tom's first comment would do it, set the blog page to display full post content and limit the number posts displayed to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom template for showing current post on your home page. Using
 `'orderby' => 'date'`

Like this example...

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1,  'orderby' => 'date' );
```